# Searching by Filename and by Category

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, search

Hi fellow developers. I'm creating a webpage to display documents. I'm trying to search
by 'filename' and by 'category'. I have a dropdown for selecting file categories and a
search input. So I created two event listeners, one to search by file name and the other
to search by category. I have many categories and I want to use the same function to
search through all my categories.

Here is my difficulties:
I have one search input and my two event listers use the same input
reference(id="search"). So at the moment I can only search by filename or by category

```
Here is my HTML code:


<section id="top1">
    <div class="top-left">
        <span><i class="mdi mdi-cloud-search"></i></span>
        <div class="dropDown">
              <select id="selectbox1" onchange="selectOption(this.value)">
                    <option value="file_name" class="file_name">File Name</option>
                    <option value="probation" class="probation">Probation 
                Review</option>
                    <option value="signed" class="signed">Signed Policies</option>
                    <option value="sick" class="sick">Sick Notes</option>
                    <option value="family" class="family">Family Responsibility Leave</option>
                    <option value="private" class="private">Private</option>
                    <option value="warnings" class="warnings">Warnings</option>
                    <option value="assets" class="assets">Assets</option>
                    <option value="certificates" class="certificates">Certificates</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="search">
            <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="search" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="upload">
        <button>Upload Files</button>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- #1documents row -->
<section class="reuse">
    <h3>Probation Reviews</h3>
    <div class="documents first-section" id="probation-review">
        
    </div>
</section>

<!-- #2documents row -->
<section class="reuse ">
    <h3>Signed Policies</h3>
    <div class="documents first-section" id="signed-policies">
    </div>
</section>

<!-- #3documents row -->
<section class="reuse">
    <h3>Sick Notes</h3>
    <div class="documents first-section" id="sick-notes">
    </div>
</section>
```

I created an array in the js file for my documents and looped them to display.
Here is the code below.

```
    /*Sick Notes*/

 const sick_note_arry = [
  { path: "https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk-demo/PDFs/Bodea Brochure.pdf", title: "Clinics", sub_title: "1 Jan 2022 10:15" },
  { path: "assets/textFiles/sample3.txt", title: "Doctors", sub_title: "1 Jan 2022 10:15" },
  { path: "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20210101201653/PDF.pdf", title: "Dr Appointment", sub_title: "1 Jan 2022 10:15" },
  // "assets/wordDocs/TeamMeeting.docx",
]
const mainCard = document.getElementById("sick-notes");

for (var i = 0; i < sick_note_arry.length; i++) {

  const newCard = document.createElement("div");
  newCard.classList.add("myDocs");
  mainCard.classList.add("first-section");

  cardHtml = `
 <div class="innerDoc">
 <iframe src="${sick_note_arry[i].path}" alt="" width='200px' height='200px' ></iframe>
 <h5>${sick_note_arry[i].title}</h5>
 <h6>${sick_note_arry[i].sub_title}</h6>
 </div>
 `;

  mainCard.appendChild(newCard);
  newCard.innerHTML = cardHtml;
}
/*End Of Sick Notes*/
```

Here is my event listener for searching by file name.

```
   const get_input =  document.getElementById("search");
   const inner_div = document.getElementsByClassName("myDocs");
   get_input.addEventListener("keyup", (event)=>{
   const valueKey = event.target.value;
   const search_items =  document.querySelectorAll(".myDocs h5");

  for (var i = 0; i < search_items.length; i++) {
    const myElements = search_items[i].innerHTML;
    
    if (myElements.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(valueKey.trim().toLowerCase()) > -1) {
      inner_div[i].style.display = "block";
  } else {
      inner_div[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  }
})
```

And here is the event for searching by category:

```
const inner_diver = document.querySelectorAll("#probation-review .myDocs");
get_input.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
const valueKey = e.target.value;

for (var i = 0; i < inner_diver.length; i++) {
const myElements = inner_diver[i].innerHTML;

if (myElements.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(valueKey.trim().toLowerCase()) > -1) {
  inner_diver[i].style.display = "block";
} else {
  inner_diver[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

}
})

My desired outcome is to have one function for searching through all categories. I'm a
beginner so I hope my question is clear. I would appreciate it if the solution could be
in javascript or jquery. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you know document's categories ? It look likes you search inside the html if the desired category occures, I'm wrong ?

Comment: You are not wrong.  In the Html example above I only posted 3 categories, " probation-review",  "signed policies" and "sick notes". I gave them different Id so I can group them by category.

Comment: So what you want to do is not hide / display `.docs`, but display the `div` which represente the categorie you selected ?

Comment: Yes , that's the functionality I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
let selectCategory = document.querySelector('#selectbox1');
let divsCategory = document.querySelectorAll('.documents');

selectCategory.addEventListener('change', e => {
    for(let div of divsCategory) {
        if(div.Id == selectCategory.value || !selectCategory.value) {
            div.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
});
```

Don't forget to add an empty `option` that will allow you to unselect `option` and so display all categories.

If you have any question / issu with this code, tell me ;)

Comment: I tested this code but its not working as expected. First , I want to search all documents(.myDocs). And second , I want to search by category(category.ID .myDocs).

Comment: This code just display category (`div`) selected in the `#selectbox1`, does it works for this ?